# Rolling window slider::slide() with grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

In the following example I try to compute the first coefficient from a linear model for time t = 1 until t. It's an expanding rolling window.

It works well with ungrouped data, but when grouped by case, I get the error `Error: Column`coef1`must be length 10 (the group size) or one, not 30`.

How can I handle grouped data?

```
library(dplyr)
library(slider)

get_coef1 <- function(data) {
  coef1 <- lm(data = data, r1 ~ r2 + r3) %>% 
    coef() %>%
    .["r2"] %>% 
    unname()

  return(coef1)
}

data <- tibble(t = rep(1:10, 3), 
               case = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10)),
               r1 = rnorm(30),
               r2 = rnorm(30),
               r3 = rnorm(30))

data %>% 
  # ungroup() %>%
  group_by(case) %>%
  mutate(coef1 = slider::slide_dbl(., ~get_coef1(.x),
                               .before = Inf, .complete = T))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first `tidyr::nest` the cases. Within the nested `tibbles` (accessed via `purrr::map`) you can then apply `slide` (same technique as with `purrr::map`). The important point is that you do not want to `slide` across cases, but only within cases.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(slider)

get_coef1 <- function(data) {
  coef1 <- lm(data = data, r1 ~ r2 + r3) %>% 
    coef() %>%
    .["r2"] %>% 
    unname()

  return(coef1)
}

data <- tibble(t = rep(1:10, 3), 
               case = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10)),
               r1 = rnorm(30),
               r2 = rnorm(30),
               r3 = rnorm(30))

data %>% 
  # ungroup() %>%
  group_by(case) %>% nest() %>%
  mutate(rollreg = map(data, ~ .x %>% mutate(coef1 = slider::slide_dbl(., ~get_coef1(.x), .before = Inf, .complete = TRUE)))) %>%
  select(-data) %>% unnest(rollreg)
```

I have been trying for a while to use the new `dplyr::nest_by()` from dplyr 1.0.0 trying to use `summarise` in combination with the `rowwise` cases but couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post, but for the sake of completeness, I offer another solution. Is this what you're looking for? Two subtle changes to the arguments to slide_dbl. The code runs.

```
data %>% 
  # ungroup() %>%
  group_by(case) %>%
  mutate(coef1 = slider::slide_dbl(.x = cur_data(), # use cur_data() instead of .; arg .x
                                   .f = ~get_coef1(.x), # arg .f
                               .before = Inf, .complete = T))
```

See the slider() documentation for underlying reasons.